# How to pass NM cable through framing for fixture centered on gable end

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, framing, roof, attic

I am looking to install a light fixture above my garage for my driveway. I would like the fixture to be centered, however this falls right against a stud on the framing. Is it permissible to drill a hole for the NM cable through this stud? Some sources seemed to indicate roof framing members were not allowed to be notched or drilled, but I am not sure if this applies to vertical studs or just trusses. I circled the stud in question and the approximate desired location of the fixture on the outside.

I am looking at "[2308.7.4 Notches and Holes](https://up.codes/viewer/maryland/ibc-2021/chapter/23/wood#2308.7.4)" in the IBC and it appears that roof framing members may have holes that are not within 2 inches of the end and not more than 1/3 of the depth of the member (so 1/2 inch through a 2x4).

[image: Attic framing]

[image: Outside gable end]

Comment: @KenCarlson Write it up and +1

Comment: I was thinking what Ken wrote as well. Also, there's almost no framing member which you can't punch a single 5/8" hole through flat-wise without consequence. Many have _knots_ larger than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that's even a framing member, it looks to me it's only job is to connect the two adjacent sheets of plywood sheathing.

But in any case, a single hole just large enough for an NM cable centered on that stud to allow entrance to a pancake box mounted to the outside of the sheathing shouldn't compromise anything. As @isherwood mentions about framing lumber in general:

> there's almost no framing member which you can't punch a single 5/8" hole through flat-wise without consequence. Many have knots larger than that.